# How to add boxshadow at the top of an image in react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo

How do I go about adding a shadow coming down at the top of an image?

here's an example:

[image]

I tried putting a dummy View tag above my Image tag and have a shadow come from it but it seems like the shadow height is always a multiplier of the elements height. so unless I make my view really big the shadow will be tiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any better way to do it without this library. give it a try https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

Sample Code would be like:

```
<Header>
  <LinearGradient
    start={{x: 0.0, y: 0.25}} end={{x: 0.5, y: 1.0}}
    locations={[0,0.5,0.6]}
    colors={['#000000', '#00000000']}>
    <YourMenuItem />
  </LinearGradient>
</Header>
```

Comment: Your post made me realize that Expo has a LinearGradient component. So for anyone using expo that's seeing this question go here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient.html otherwise that library that you linked is the way to go it seems!

Comment: cool @ShayanJavadi, better using built-in component than add redundant one.